# A blue background and an image

Tags: ios, image, background

I made a simple application with a color blue background and an image on the top. When I run it, it gives me a white color or nothing!

Does anyone know?

Comment: Please post any relevant code or screenshot of ui. We can't translate those .... to code and identify what is the problem

Comment: My guess is you've done something wrong. And that's literally the most helpful answer anyone can give you as your question currently stands. Please update it with more information on the problem (code, expected behaviour, screenshots if necessary). Also, questions without any evidence of research are generally frowned upon. Please also detail what you have already tried to do in order to solve this problem.

Comment: Usually we make imageView as an outlet and accordingly we show or hide our images. Here you need to set the image like xyz.png into your imageView either through code or through interface builder and it will show, or otherwise place the breakpoint upon the imageView ivar and see for yourself what is the value.

Comment: check once your viewcontroller background color is white on anywhere, at the same time check once your image path is correct or not

Answer (score 0):

Usually we make imageView as an outlet and accordingly we show or hide our images. Here you need to set the image like xyz.png into your imageView either through code or through interface builder and it will show, or otherwise place the breakpoint upon the imageView ivar and see for yourself what is the value. – Kumar Utsav just now   edit

Comment: I don't see how you can post this as an answer when the OP has told us absolutely nothing about what they've done.

Comment: I would be suggesting him to watch the basic tutorials to reach to this conclusion.

Comment: What does that have to do with your "answer"? The question is terrible. It needs to be closed, not answered. You shouldn't post an answer to such a vague question.

Comment: I don't know how to do it! I get the message: Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?

Comment: Look for the arrow mark. Or set the entry point for the view controller in the interface builder. It is like this -> in storyboard pointing as the entry point. Good Luck !

Comment: What @rmaddy said is 100% true. I wish you could have voted to close this question rather than answering. In it's current format it deserves that.

Comment: Allow the buddy wings to grow, grant them blessing. Keep it up! Learn debugging and try hard, that's how I got started. Learning other programming languages and their debugging skills can help you immensely. Ready Programming for dummies. I want you to succeed no matter what. Have courage!

Comment: @Sameeha You need to update your question with more details about your issue. Update your question with what you have actually done and any errors your may be getting. As written, it is impossible to help you.

Comment: I created a new project, connection my iPhone 4 and I got this message: Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?

Comment: @Sameeha Posting comments to this answer is not the same as updating your question. Put all relevant information in your question, not in comments.

Comment: I created another project, it's the same as the precious project.